# Listening a event from other form in WPF

Tags: wpf, events

Do you know how event from "Add_Form" can be listened from "MainForm"? I code in WPF 2010(Visual Studio).

My program has two forms - "MainForm" and "Add_Form". "MainForm" has "Student_DataGrid" which has a register of students and button("btn_add_student") which invokes "Add_Form"(Form which has textblocks for input data of students). After clicking "btn_add_student" shows "Add_Form", further, I fill in data in textblocks and push the button "btn_add_student". New student is added in Data Base and "Add_form" is closed. Then "Student_DataGrid" on "MainForm" must be reloaded.

In other words I want to listen event on Add_Form from MainForm. I can do it in C#, but I can't do it in WPF. I'll be glad to any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you haven't explored the strength of WPF i.e. `Binding`. These tutorials will get you going [Binding Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140621/WPF-Tutorial-Concept-Binding) and one from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

All you need to do in your case is bind your grid to an `ObservableCollection` and while adding a new student, `add the object in this collection`. Grid will automatically get refreshed.

Comment: If a programmer adds data through DataGrid, it will be work. But when Data(Students) add from another form("Add_Form") it doesn't work as I have two different forms:).

Answer (score 1):

If "Add_Form" and "MainForm" are binding to the same source, "Student_DataGrid" on "MainForm" needn't reloaded.
WPF can do it for u.

Comment: no, it's two different forms and I add data in DataGrid through DataTable

Answer (score -1):

I found the way to solve it:).
I just made whole class of events:).
[Here you are!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms#_rating)